# Spring authentication without role authorization?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am new to spring security and learning it. I was looking for simple authentication process in Spring security where user enters his
 credentials and spring security authenticates it. Go this link [mykong simple authentication example](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-http-basic-authentication-example/).
 But everywhere on net like in this example i see  configuration like below

```
     <http>
            <intercept-url pattern="/welcome*" access="ROLE_USER" />
            <http-basic />
        </http>

        <authentication-manager>
           <authentication-provider>
               <user-service>
               <user name="mkyong" password="123456" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
               </user-service>
           </authentication-provider>
        </authentication-manager>
```

Here if user access any URL with pattern /welcome*, Two steps will take place :-

1)he will be authenticated for user name as "mkyong" and password as "123456"

2)Spring will also check if user has role "ROLE_USER"

What i am looking for is just for step where user is authenticated for credentials but not for role? I am sure it should be minor change in configuration.
But could not spot it

Comment: Don't assign a role, just require an authenticated user - `access="isAuthenticated()"`, don't forget to set `use-expressions="true"` as per [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13384838/2071828). Also **don't use XML**, use [JavaConfig](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.x/guides/helloworld.html). If you are "new to Spring Security" then don't learn obsolete techniques.

Comment: Thanks Boris the spider

Comment: may refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32685057/spring-security-user-class-without-userrole-roles-authentication-only-no-au