# Spring security : User class without UserRole (roles). Authentication only no authorization needed

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-boot

I'm using Spring-security with Spring-boot. My Application is a POC, for the moment there is no need to have Role.

I was wondering if it is possible to have a Custom `UserDetailsService` which return `UserDetails` in `loadUserByUsername` method but without the `GrantedAuthority` nor `UserRole` class.

I have googled all the day long for an example but I always get them with the `UserRole`.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not give every authenticated user a default role? I don't think you can configure spring security without roles.

Comment: I think you are right, but the thing is i could define an application with authentication only and possibly extend it to have authorization and not to be obliged to have them both.

Comment: anyone has git project which only takes user name and password to authenticate and create a session for that user?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work:

1. Let *UserDetails* return an empty collection in `getAuthorities()`:

   ```
   public class User implements UserDetails {
       ...
       @Override
       public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {        
           return new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>();
       }
   }
   ```
2. Use just `authenticated()` while configuring security

   ```
   http.authorizeRequests()
       ...
       .antMatchers("/foo").authenticated()
       ...
   ```

Comment: Okay for the first part but why the second part?

Comment: Its because you want to use authentication only and not authorization.